# How can I rename a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, collections, rename

Is there a dead easy way to rename a collection in mongo?  Something like:

```
db.originalCollectionName.rename('newCollectionName');
```

And if not, what is the best way to go about effectively renaming one?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Close. Use `db.originalCollectionName.renameCollection('newCollectionName')`

See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/renameCollection+Command

Comment: hint: try using tab complete to find things you think might be there ;)

Comment: +1 I also found that this will error if the collection that you wish to rename to (the 'target collection name') already exists. IF you are happy for said collection to be **dropped**; then you can pass 'true' as the second argument, e.g. `db.originalCollName.renameCollection('alreadyExistingCollName', true)`

Comment: after the rename, will the indexes and everything be kept?

Comment: How can I make the `old` one variable, such as `db[old].rename..`?

Answer (score 19):

For those who cannot rename, because the name causes an issue like: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL, it is because the name is illegal.

You can work around this by calling with brackets notation: `db["oldCollectionILLEGALName"].renameCollection("someBetterName")`

Comment: `db.getCollection("oldCollectionILLEGALName").renameCollection("someBetterName")` should also work. I had renamed my collection to `_old_collection_name` and this saved me.

Comment: Thanks buddy, this solved my issue. 

I am currently learning Mongo and in a rush I ended up naming my collection as 'employee-detail' and was stuck with the error.

This was a good learning.

Answer (score 18):

Assume that the database name is "**mytestdb**" and collection name is "**orders**". collection name change to **orders2015** The simplest way is,

```
> use mytestdb
> db.orders.renameCollection( "orders2015" )
```

**Note :** db.collection.renameCollection() is not supported on sharded collections.

Comment: Answer from 2015 still valid as of today, plus one.

Answer (score 6):

In case you are using Node.js MongoDB driver:

```
mongoClient.db(dbName).collection('oldName').rename("newName");
```

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#rename

my case was using mongoose:

```
await mongoose.connection.collection("oldName").rename("newName");
```

Comment: Always remember, `mongo` is not `js` is not `nodejs`. So look at the difference, therefore plus one.

Answer (score 2):

Rename a collection in cmd:

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin
mongo
use yourdb
db.yourcollection.renameCollection("someBetterName")
```

This example is made for MongoDB 4.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax to rename an existing collection in MongoDB.

`db.originalCollectionName.renameCollection('newCollectionName')`

For instance, if your existing collection name is 'demo' and want to rename to 'demo_updated' then, the query would be as follows:-

```
db.demo.renameCollection('demo_updated')
```

Thanks!