# MongoDB and Nest.js: Define a custom name for a collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, nestjs

I have a schema like this:

```
    @Schema()
    export class Pais extends Document {
      @Prop(
        raw({
          codigo: { type: String, index: true, unique: true },
        }),
      )
      @Prop()
      descripcion: string;
    }
    
    export const PaisSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Pais);
    
    PaisSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: `{PATH} debe ser único` });
```

By default nest.js add an 's' to the class name, so it would be 'paiss' for the collection, but I want the name to be 'paises'.

On the module I tried this:

```
    @Module({
      imports: [
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'paises', schema: PaisSchema }]),
      ],
```

but it didn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does mongoose always add an s to the end of my collection name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547118/why-does-mongoose-always-add-an-s-to-the-end-of-my-collection-name)

Comment: I would like to do it with the decorators approach to take advantage of the nestjs functionalities, however I already did it, thanks.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

i found a solution, just had to set the @Schema() decorator like this

```
@Schema({ collection: 'paises' })
```

Comment: How to get it from env? I mean the collection name like process.env.MY_COLLECTION?

Answer (score 1):

this is Not true

```
@Schema({ collection: 'paises' })
```

You can collection name in module file

```
MongooseModule.forFeature([{name : 'paises' , schema : PaisSchema }])
```

and in service File :

```
@InjectModel('paises') public model: paisesModel<paisesDocument>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. If you have already create a collection and want to rename it from plural name for to a single one, you might wanna check this answer: [How can I rename a collection in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732553/how-can-i-rename-a-collection-in-mongodb) via mongo shell or [renaming a collection with mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28280847/renaming-a-collection-with-mongodb) for Native JS driver.

If you want to define your own schema name and avoid this `pluralizing` collection form, try to use [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/index.html) driver. It allows you to define you own schema / model and name it exactly as you want. To achieve this, use snippet below:

```
let schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
    },
    other_field: String
},{
    /** Schema options*/
    timestamps: true
});

let model_db = mongoose.model('collection_name', schema, 'collection');
```

But! Always make sure that your collection name doesn't break any [MongoDB name restictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#restrictions-on-db-names).