# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MongooseCoreModule (MongooseConnectionName, ?)

Tags: javascript, nestjs

`Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MongooseCoreModule (MongooseConnectionName, ?). Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index [1] is available in the MongooseCoreModule context.`

I am new to nest and am facing this issue, the app.controller.ts is

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ItemsController } from './items.controller';
import { ItemsService } from './items.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ItemSchema } from './schema/item.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{name:'Item',schema:ItemSchema}])],
  controllers: [ItemsController],
  providers: [ItemsService],
})
export class ItemsModule {}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: this is likely due to multiple modules loaded for the same `@nestjs/core` package. If you're in a monorepo, see this: https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/pull/2152/files

Comment: I think my error is first one, how to resolve that?

Comment: not having `@nestjs/core` as hard dependency in your side. Without context, it's hard to tell why you end up with many `@nestjs/core`.

Answer (score 1):

In you case, you can try to add this to your ItemSchema :

```js
// schema/item.schema

@Schema({ collection: 'items' })
```

And make sure the import with a plural name :

```js
// items.module.ts

// [...]
@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{name:'items',schema:ItemSchema}])],
  controllers: [ItemsController],
  providers: [ItemsService],
})
export class ItemsModule {}
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63236438/11924554).

Or if you prefer to keep the name schema name `item`, you can force it by following  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10559895/11924554)

> Mongoose is trying to be smart by making your collection name plural. You can however force it to be whatever you want:
>
> var dataSchema = new Schema({..}, { collection: 'data' })

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error while i am learning Connecting Nest.js with Azure Cosmos DB.
Error : "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AzureCosmosDbCoreModule (COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_NAME, ?). Please make sure that the argument ModuleRef at index [1] is available in the AzureCosmosDbCoreModule context.

```
Potential solutions:
- Is AzureCosmosDbCoreModule a valid NestJS module?
- If ModuleRef is a provider, is it part of the current AzureCosmosDbCoreModule?
- If ModuleRef is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AzureCosmosDbCoreModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ModuleRef */ ]
  })"
Here is the solution: 
Check your dependencies in the Package.json file.

"dependencies": {
    "@azure/cosmos": "^3.17.3",
    "@nestjs/azure-database": "^2.3.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.1.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@nestjs/azure-database": {
      "@nestjs/common": "^9.1.4",
      "@nestjs/core": "^9.1.4"
    } 
This may help you!.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you dont `start` your code in the proper directory in your program folder. So `cd` navigate to the directory of your project and and run all the codes again.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you have @nestjs/core and @nestjs/commons installed with different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `node_modules` and run `npm/yarn/pnpm install`. It worked for my project.